# Whats the difference between dart run vs flutter pub run

Tags: flutter, mockito, dart-pub, flutter-pub

I downloaded the Mockito library (https://pub.dev/packages/mockito) and followed the instruction to use "dart run build_runner build" to generate mocks in my project directory and it failed with the following error.

```
Could not find a file named "pubspec.yaml" in "/Users/mark/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/_fe_analyzer_shared-31.0.0".
#0      new Pubspec.load (package:pub/src/pubspec.dart:288:7)
#1      new Package.load (package:pub/src/package.dart:149:27)
#2      SystemCache.load (package:pub/src/system_cache.dart:113:20)
#3      Entrypoint._createPackageGraph (package:pub/src/entrypoint.dart:112:63)
#4      Entrypoint.packageGraph (package:pub/src/entrypoint.dart:107:54)
#5      getExecutableForCommand (package:pub/src/executable.dart:338:19)
#6      RunCommand.run (package:dartdev/src/commands/run.dart:232:32)
#7      CommandRunner.runCommand (package:args/command_runner.dart:209:27)
#8      DartdevRunner.runCommand (package:dartdev/dartdev.dart:232:30)
#9      CommandRunner.run.<anonymous closure> (package:args/command_runner.dart:119:25)
#10     new Future.sync (dart:async/future.dart:296:31)
#11     CommandRunner.run (package:args/command_runner.dart:119:14)
#12     runDartdev (package:dartdev/dartdev.dart:67:29)
#13     main (file:///opt/s/w/ir/cache/builder/sdk/pkg/dartdev/bin/dartdev.dart:11:9)
#14     _delayEntrypointInvocation.<anonymous closure> (dart:isolate-patch/isolate_patch.dart:293:32)
#15     _RawReceivePortImpl._handleMessage (dart:isolate-patch/isolate_patch.dart:192:12)
```

However if I followed the instructions in Flutter's cookbook(https://docs.flutter.dev/cookbook/testing/unit/mocking#3-create-a-test-file-with-a-mock-httpclient) and used "flutter pub run build_runner build" in the project directory it works.

What are the differences between dart run and flutter pub run? Why dart run tries to execute from the /Users/username/.pub-cache directory when I am executing it from the project directory?

I saw this related issue in Mockit, however it does not explain the differences. (https://github.com/dart-lang/mockito/issues/435)